# HtmlUnit stays logged in after removing "JSESSIONID" cookie

Tags: java, session, cookies, authentication, htmlunit

I'm setting up remember-me authentication for my Spring Boot application an want to write a HtmlUnit test.
The problem is that deleting the "JSESSIONID" cookie does not seem to log out the webClient.
The test using remember-me authentication works fine but the test in which there should be no authentication and thus a redirect to the login page does not work (the last assertion fails).

```
@Test
void NoRememberMeLogin() throws IOException {
    HtmlPage loginPage = webClient.getPage(baseURL + "login");
    HtmlForm loginForm = loginPage.getFormByName("loginForm");
    HtmlInput username = loginForm.getInputByName("username");
    HtmlInput password = loginForm.getInputByName("password");
    HtmlCheckBoxInput rememberMe = loginForm.getInputByName("remember-me");

    username.setValueAttribute("user");
    password.setValueAttribute("password");
    rememberMe.setChecked(false);

    // login
    HtmlElement submit = loginForm.getOneHtmlElementByAttribute("input", "type", "submit");
    HtmlPage afterLogin = submit.click();
    // login successful?
    assertThat(afterLogin.getUrl().toString(), is(baseURL + "securedPage"));

    // checkl cookies
    Cookie sessionCookie = webClient.getCookieManager().getCookie("JSESSIONID");
    Cookie rememberMeCookie = webClient.getCookieManager().getCookie("remember-me");
    assertNotNull(sessionCookie);
    assertNull(rememberMeCookie);

    // delete the Session cookie
    webClient.getCookieManager().removeCookie(sessionCookie);
    sessionCookie = webClient.getCookieManager().getCookie("JSESSIONID");
    // session cookie really is deleted
    assertNull(sessionCookie);

    // refresh tha page (works in browser)
    afterLogin.refresh();
    // check that we were redirected to login page (not working)
    assertThat(afterLogin.getUrl().toString(), is(baseURL + "login"));
}
```

Hope you can help me, thanks!

Comment: Can you please check what is going on (or wrong) on the wire. You can use a proxy like Charles to capture the traffic. Two questions to answer: does afterLogin.refresh(); connects the server again and if you doe it send the removed cookie. Will be great if you can open an HtmlUnit issue (Github) about this and we can discuss the problem there in more detail.

Comment: I tried it with Charles but it does not capture the requests. It does capture the requests to the server when running manuall instead of inside the tests though. So it's not a localhost problem. Maybe because of springs's MockMvc?
Do you think I should open a GitHub issue now?

Comment: I guess is a cache problem in HtmlUnit, try to call webClient.getCache().clear(); right before the refresh call.

Comment: That did not help, however I looked through the logs of all the MockHttpServletRequest and it seems, that the second request is sent without the cookie. So HtmlUnit seems to do it correctly

Comment: It works when creating the webClient like this:
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

The problem only arises when spring boot autoconfigures the WebClient.
I might open an issue there